# No embedded container found. Running as CLI application

Tags: java, maven, jar, micronaut

I have build an application in java micronaut framework with maven.

I have create application jar file for the application. when I have run that jar file with

> java -jar XXXXXXXX-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

the application is running successfully but how do I know on which port  actually the application is running.

Actual behaviour:
It should be run on the localhost port:8080

Expected Behaviour:
but It is showing as :  No embedded container found. Running as CLI application.

Please guide me appropriately.

Thank You!!!

Comment: Micronaut Application projects created with Micronaut Launch or CLI don't create a jar file named `jar-with-dependencies`. See https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/creating-your-first-micronaut-app-maven-java.html for an example of creating an application with Launch or CLI. Most of the Micronaut guides have Maven examples (https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/index.html).

Comment: "Micronaut Application projects created with Micronaut Launch or CLI don't create a jar file named jar-with-dependencies" - The Gradle build could be configured to name the generated jar anything you like as long as it is a valid file name on the file system.  I assume that the `XXXXXXXX-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar` mentioned in the question is not the actual file name.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for the my question.
I have issue that I'm not able to run jar file on port:8080 or any port configure in project. Becuase I am using micronuat version 2.2.0.
I had upgraded the micronaut version to latest version i.e micronut version3.7.4 and this solve my issue. Now I'm able to run jar file on port.

Thank you..